# Passing compressed files from C# to R

Tags: c#, r

I don't know very well C# and compressed files, but i need to create comrpessed files with C# and read them with R. So which format should i use, that it is compatible with both C# and R?
I have tried this:

```
 using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream("myfile.gff", FileMode.Create))
 {
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry write_entry = archive.CreateEntry(path);
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(write_entry.Open()))
        {
          //writing 
        }
    }
 }
```

but i can't open this file with the R function `unzip()`.

*EDIT*:

```
zipF<-file.choose()
unzip(zipF)
```

*Warning message: In unzip(zipF) : error 1 in extracting from zip file*

Comment: What error message is shown/printed?

Comment: is the zip file created correctly in C# ?

Comment: The zip file is correctly created in C#. I can write and read it in C#

Comment: can you open the zip file with other tools like windows explorer?